# auto-size text in a collapsible tree based on amount of expanded components within container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey so I'm writing a code to create a expandable/collapsible tree using checkboxes. I've got that part down, but I was wanting to make it so that the more you expand the tree, the smaller the text gets so that the user doesn't need to scroll around to view all of the expanded branches. 
I came across the jQuery plugin, TextFill but can't quite get it to work the way I want it to (not even sure if it's compatible with what I'm doing).

So, here's a snippet of the code

```css
/*better tree view*/
 html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
/*kingdom*/
 html .kingdom, body .kingdom {
    color: #0000ff;
}
html .kingdom:hover, body .kingdom:hover {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
li .kingdom + input[type=checkbox] + ul > li {
    display: none;
}
li .kingdom + input[type=checkbox]:checked + ul > li {
    display: block;
}
/*phylum*/
 html .phylum, body .phylum {
    color: #ff0000;
}
html .phylum:hover, body .phylum:hover {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
html .class, body .class {
    color: #008000;
}
html .class:hover, body .class:hover {
    background-color: #008000;
}
html .order, body .order {
    color: #800080;
}
html .order:hover, body .order:hover {
    background-color: #800080;
}
html .family, body .family {
    color: #ffa500;
}
html .family:hover, body .family:hover {
    background-color: #ffa500;
}
html .genus, body .genus {
    color: #ffc0cb;
}
html .genus:hover, body .genus:hover {
    background-color: #ffc0cb;
}
html .subgenus, body .subgenus {
    color: #a52a2a;
}
html .subgenus:hover, body .subgenus:hover {
    background-color: #a52a2a;
}
html .species, body .species {
    color: #000000;
}
html .species:hover, body .species:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
}
html .subspecies, body .subspecies {
    color: #808080;
}
html .subspecies:hover, body .subspecies:hover {
    background-color: #808080;
}
.treeview {
    float: left;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.treeview:hover input ~ label:before, .treeview.hover input ~ label:before {
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.treeview ul {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
.treeview ul li span {
    -webkit-transition-property: color;
    -moz-transition-property: color;
    -ms-transition-property: color;
    -o-transition-property: color;
    transition-property: color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
.treeview ul li span:hover {
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.treeview input {
    display: none;
    /*arrow thing*/
}
.treeview input ~ label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.treeview input ~ label:before {
    content:'';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -1em;
    margin-top: 0.4em;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color: black;
    border-right-color: black;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.0;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -ms-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
.treeview input:checked ~ label:before {
    margin-left: -0.8em;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: black;
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
input + label + ul {
    display:none;
}
input:checked + label + ul {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
    <div class="treeview hover">
  <ul>
    <li>
       <input type="checkbox" id="cbanimalia"/>
      <label class="kingdom" for="cbanimalia">
          <span>Animalia</span>
          </label>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cbchordata" />
            <label class="phylum" for="cbchordata"> <span>Chordata</span>
            </label>
            <ul>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cbmammalia" />
                <label class="class" for="cbmammalia"> <span>Mammalia</span>
                </label>
                <ul>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="cbcarnivora" />
                    <label class="order" for="cbcarnivora"> <span>Carnivora</span>
                    </label>
                    <ul>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbcarnidae" />
                        <label class="family" for="cbcarnidae"> <span>Carnidae</span>
                        </label>
                        <ul>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="cbcanis" />
                            <label class="genus" for="cbcanis"> <span>Canis</span>
                            </label>
                            <ul>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="cbspecies" />
                                <label class="species" for="cbspecies"> <span><i>Canis lupis</i></span>
                                </label>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="http://thegrassisstillgreen.weebly.com/animal-count--domestic-dog.html"><label class="subspecies"><span><i>Canis lupis familiaris</i></span></label></li></a>

                                </ul>
                            </ul>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbrodentia" />
                        <label class="order" for="cbrodentia"> <span>Rodentia</span>
                        </label>
                        <ul>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="cbsciuridae" />
                            <label class="family" for="cbsciuridae"> <span>Sciuridae</span>
                            </label>
                            <ul>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="cbsciuris" />
                                <label class="genus" for="cbsciuris"> <span>Sciuris</span>
                                </label>
                                <ul>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="cbsciuris2" />
                                    <label class="subgenus" for="cbsciuris2"> <span>Sciuris</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="http://thegrassisstillgreen.weebly.com/animal-count--red-squirrel.html"><label class="species"><span><i>Sciuris vulgaris</i></span></label></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </ul>
                            </ul>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Been working at this for a while now - any help would be appreciated!

By the way, my code may look really terrible and unorganized because I'm fairly new at it. I'm pretty much just frankenstein-ing a bunch of different pieces together. :p

Thanks for your time, and hope you guys can figure this out!

Comment: I don't quite get what you want.

Comment: If you run the code snippet, you will see that as you click on the text entries (animalia, chordata, etc.) that you will have to scroll down to continue to expand the branches. What I am hoping to accomplish is to have the text adjust its size based on the amount of content within the window. 
So less text expanded = larger text.
more text expanded = smaller text.
So that all expanded text is viewable despite the number of branches opened.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Maybe you should consider another navigational method that better suits your needs. Like the Mac OS column view that later evolved into the iOS folder navigation. Or if you absolutely want to keep it as a tree, automatically scroll down when opening a node.

Comment: Hey Jan,  thanks for your advice. Keeping the tree aspect is essential for me as it is meant to eventually be a tree of life (that's why I have the weird sciency animal names as the branches).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use javascript, this will change the font size based on the depth of the item clicked within the collapsible tree.

You can tweak the amount of "shrinkage" by adjusting the font size equation.  Change the initial font size, multiplier, or minimum value to suit your needs.

```
$("label").click(function (element) {
    var depth = $(this).parents().length;
    // Font size of 8 will be the minimum:
    var fontSize = Math.max(40 - depth * 2, 8);
    $(".treeview.hover li").css({
        "font-size": fontSize
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/umc2vjw1/

Comment: Cheers, it was a fun, unique problem with the restrictions.